# A Trivial Pursuit #16 (Art and Literature 3/4): X

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, literature

<sub>This is part 16 of [A Trivial Pursuit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a60644%20is%3aq%20%22a%20trivial%20pursuit%22&searchOn=3), a 25-part puzzle hunt. Each part is solvable on its own, with the exception of the meta-puzzle at the end.</sub>

---

[image: Grid of 25 letters, with 8 bullet-point clues along each side]

**The final answer is a thematic 8-letter word.**

> *Text content of image (for accessibility):*
>
> - Grid rows: CHARM; PULSE; FAXED; TIBIA; WONKY.
> - 8 bullets on left side (top to bottom): Animal fibre; "Fight For You" singer; Mesopotamian goddess, daughter of Anu; Owned; Potassium; Quarrel; Roseanne?; Samos International Airport.
> - 8 bullets at top (left to right): Boot; Grandmother; Incisor; Redden; Rock band; Royal Navy 'soldier slang'; Scottish girl; White.
> - 8 bullets on right side (top to bottom): 15 in hexadecimal; Deprecated Microsoft web browser; Georgia (country); James Bond's boss; King, or Cheadle?; *Lotidae* member; Period of darkness; Thorium.
> - 8 bullets at bottom (left to right): ADD OWN FUNNEL; FIRE WRITER OR EX; INERT CARRIER; LATIN ADAM; LOOPED; OCEAN PRICKLES; ORIOLE GULCH; URBAN HOOD.

Comment: Eight is a lucky. @Stiv.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The final answer is:

> **Alsatian**

Getting there:
First, some answers to the clues around the grid:

Left:

> Animal fibre; **Wool**
>  "Fight For You" singer; **H.E.R**
>  Mesopotamian goddess, daughter of Anu - **Bau**
>  Owned - **Had**
>  Potassium - **K**
>  Quarrel - **Row**
>  Roseanne? - **Barr**
>  Samos International Airport - IATA code **SMI**

Right:

> 15 in hexadecimal - **F**
>  Deprecated Microsoft web browser - **I.E.** (Internet Explorer)
>  Georgia (country) - **GE** (country code)
>  James Bond's boss - **M**
>  King, or Cheadle? - **Don**
>  Lotidae member - **Ling**
>  Period of darkness - **Night**
>  Thorium - **Th**

Top:

> Boot - **Wellington**
>  Grandmother - **Nana**
>  Incisor - **Fang**
>  Redden - **Flush**
>  Rock band - **Toto**
>  Royal Navy 'soldier slang' - **Pongo**
>  Scottish girl - **Lassie**
>  White - **Snowy**

Bottom:

> These are all anagrams of dog breeds:
>  ADD OWN FUNNEL - **Newfoundland**
>  FIRE WRITER OR EX - **Wire Fox Terrier**
>  INERT CARRIER - **Cairn Terrier**
>  LATIN ADAM - **Dalmatian**
>  LOOPED - **Poodle**
>  OCEAN PRICKLES - **Cocker Spaniel**
>  ORIOLE GULCH - **Rough Collie**
>  URBAN HOOD - **Boarhound**

Graphically:

> [image: Grid with annotated answers to clues around the edge]

Putting it all together

> The top and bottom give us the names and breeds of (mostly) fictional dogs, with the left and right joining to give us the surnames of authors who wrote about them:
>
>  **Flush** - **Cocker Spaniel** from Flush: A Biography (partly fictional, but about a real dog, hence the "mostly" above)
>  **Wool**+**F** - Virginia Woolf
>
>  **Fang** - **Boarhound** from the Harry Potter series
>  **Row+Ling** - J.K Rowling
>
>  **Pongo** - **Dalmatian** from The Hundred and One Dalmations
>  **SMI**+**Th** - Dodie Smith
>
>  **Nana** - **Newfoundland** from Peter Pan
>  **Barr**+**IE** - J.M. Barrie
>
>  **Toto** - **Cairn Terrier** from The Wonderful Wizard of Oz
>  **Bau**+**M** - L. Frank Baum
>
>  **Snowy** - **Wire Fox Terrier** from The Adventures of Tintin
>  **H.E.R**+**GE** - Hergé (pen name of Georges Prosper Remi)
>
>  **Wellington** - **Poodle** from The Curious Incident of the Dog in the Night-Time
>  **Had**+**Don** - Mark Haddon
>
>  **Lassie** - **Rough Collie** from Lassie Come Home
>  **K**+**Night** - Eric Knight

Finally:

> Taking a hint from the X in the puzzle title, and the one in the centre of the grid, let's join up the elements and see where the lines cross:
>  [image: Grid with matching entries joined]

> And reading off the circled letter in order gives us **ALSATIAN**

Comment: This is exactly right, well done :) A great write-up too, explaining everything - that's a checkmark right there! (Although actually you don't need to use an anagram at the end - you can just read it off row by row...)

Comment: Hate to nitpick on such a lovely solution, but rot13(gur yvax sebz SNAT gb OBNEUBHAQ vf zvfpbybherq).

Comment: @DanielS Indeed it is. I noticed that when editing the image and corrected it locally. I must have uploaded the earlier version.

Comment: @Stiv I tried ordering the eight groups by their various elements, none of which worked. I never thought to just try grid order.